# What is “spectral turnover”?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, frequency, radio-frequency, radio

In a paper which deals with the spectra of radio frequency cosmic events, the word “spectral turnover” is used. What is “spectral turnover”?

Comment: Can you share a link to the paper?

Answer (score 1):

It just means, that when you look at the spectrum on a log-log plot, that it become flat or even reverses slope, in contrast to a steeper power law spectrum at higher and/or lower frequencies.

There are various physical reasons why a turnover might appear in the spectrum (e.g. a flattening in the underlying power-law distribution of electrons producing synchrotron emission or synchrotron self-absorption).

I was quickly able to find the following sketch (from [this website](https://www.sao.ru/hq/giag/gps-en.html)) of a "GHz-peaked radio galaxy", which illustrates and explains the situation.

[image: GHz peaked radio source]